# What is a different between Mali OpenCL SDK and OpenCL inside OpenCV library

Tags: opencv, opencl

Do you know what is different between Mali OpenCL SDK and OpenCL in OpenCV library? I see that in Mali OpenCL SDK has some detail sample code about how to create Memory buffer, get input data, setup argument... But in OpenCL inside OpenCV library, I only need change from Mat to UMAT to have OpenCL code run on GPU? and it seems OpenCL code hidden under API? How can I change OpenCL code by my application?

Answer (score 0):

These are not the same things.

Your question is like asking what the difference between a `for-Loop` and a random method `doForLoop`that contains a `for-Loop` is.

OpenCV can use OpenCL to accelerate certain tasks.

The Mali OpenCL SDK is a SDK to program OpenCL directly. You can use this SDK to develop programs that should run on the Mail mobile graphics GPU.